# Allow selection of font used for code segments

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, code-formatting, fonts

I have several programming fonts installed on my computer and would hate to have to muck about with them to have SO display code segments in my favourite one.

Answer (score 3):

Change the font used for fixed-width text in your browser options.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do that specifying user-defined CSS (as opposed to "author-defined CSS", which is the CSS supplied by the web site) in your web browser.

Comment: Sure, I can, but it would be a good feature to have. IMHO, that functionality exists only in Firefox.

Comment: @Aviral Dasgupta - That feature is implemented in IE and in Safari too.